# Laravel 5.8 | FullCalendar display events on calendar

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I am trying to display events on calendar from this package:

```
composer require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
```

I did model:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
    ];
}
```

Event migrations with same columns. In controller I have function:

```
public function all()
    {
        $events = [];
        $data = Event::all();
        
        if($data->count()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $events[] = Calendar::event(
                    $value->title,
                    true,
                    new \DateTime($value->start_date),
                    new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day'),
                    null,
                    [
                        'color' => '#f05050',
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
        $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events);
        return view('pages.block.event.all', compact('calendar'));
    }
```

and in my all.blade.php:

```
{!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
```

the calendar is displayed correctly, but no events are applied to it. Could someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Did you add `{!! $calendar->script() !!}` to the blade as well, as per the [documentation](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)?

Comment: P.S. This madhatter library loads a **very old** version of fullCalendar - 2.2.7. The current version is 5.7. It would be far better to use the modern version (which has more features, lots of fixes, and is faster) by just including it in your blade via JS, rather than messing about with the library. You can then connect it to your event feed by making a laravel controller function which returns the events in JSON format.

Comment: do you have a source for this newer version?

Comment: Well, did you think of going to the fullcalendar website? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/#toc